Changing parentheses in footnote-dw
I am trying to change the parentheses around the "see notes" string (wie Anm. in German) to square brackets. Judging from the source code of footnote-dw (https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-dw.zip, file footnote-dw.cbx, lines 140-154), I added a redeclaration of the cite:seenote field format, however, this does not affect the result. Same if I remove the brackets altogether using
\DeclareFieldFormat{cite:seenote}{#1}

Minimal example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=footnote-dw, %Zitierstil
singletitle=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{cite:seenote}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Book{Ehlers1973,
    title      = {\frq Des Teufels Netz\flq. Untersuchung zum Gattungsproblem},
    year       = {1973},
    author     = {Ehlers, Anke},
    location   = {Stuttgart},
    series     = {Studien zur Poetik und Geschichte der Literatur 35},
    gender     = {sf},
    keywords   = {Dissertation, Teufels_Netz},
}
@Article{Mittl2014,
    author     = {Mittl, Florian},
    title      = {Der Teufel in der Literatur: \frqq Ein Teil von jener Kraft, die stets das Böse will und stets das Gute schafft.\flqq},
    journal    = {Disputatio philosophica 15/1},
    year       = {(2014)},
    shorttitle = {},
    pages      = {65--79},
    keywords   = {Dissertation, Teufel},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{Ehlers1973}
\footcite{Mittl2014}
\footcite{Ehlers1973}
\end{document}

yields


Can you run the example you posted in a new, empty folder and see what comes out? Because when I run it, I get square brackets for "[wie Anm. 1]".

Thanks for looking into this. For me its the same even in a new folder (the parentheses remain). texlive-full package version (Ubuntu 22.04) is 2021.20220204-1. Tex is TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian). Which versions were you running?

With a current version of biblatex-dw (I tried v1.7b from 2023-03-11)  redefining the field format cite:seenote as shown in the question
\DeclareFieldFormat{cite:seenote}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}} 

works just fine.
If you're using an older version (e.g. v1.6a from 2013/09/22), you can get the desired result by additionally modernising the cite:seenote bibmacro as shown below (the shown code is just a copy of the definition of that macro in v1.7b).
You may want to look into updating your TeX system. The new biblatex-dw code is much more idiomatic when it comes to this aspect of the style. (It might be possible to install the newest version of biblatex-dw locally on an older version of TeX live, cf. How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?. Usually this is not recommended, since local package installations are a major compatibility headache, but here you might be lucky.)
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=footnote-dw,
  singletitle=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{cite:seenote}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:seenote}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:review}
    {}
    {\addspace\printtext[cite:seenote]{%
     \midsentence\bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace%
     \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
     \ifbool{cbx:pageref}
       {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                   {\csuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace%
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@first@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
       {}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Ehlers1973,
    title      = {\frq Des Teufels Netz\flq. Untersuchung zum Gattungsproblem},
    year       = {1973},
    author     = {Ehlers, Anke},
    location   = {Stuttgart},
    series     = {Studien zur Poetik und Geschichte der Literatur 35},
    gender     = {sf},
    keywords   = {Dissertation, Teufels_Netz},
}
@Article{Mittl2014,
    author     = {Mittl, Florian},
    title      = {Der Teufel in der Literatur:
                  \frqq Ein Teil von jener Kraft,
                  die stets das Böse will und stets das Gute schafft.\flqq},
    journal    = {Disputatio philosophica 15/1},
    year       = {(2014)},
    shorttitle = {},
    pages      = {65--79},
    keywords   = {Dissertation, Teufel},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\footcite{Ehlers1973}
\footcite{Mittl2014}
\footcite{Ehlers1973}
\end{document}



Thanks patching biblatex-dw worked great but upgrading my TeX installation is definitely on the list once this project is over.
